# How can I print to the clipboard in OS X?

Tags: macos

OS X has useful PDF workflow functions such as "Mail PDF" and "Save as PDF...". I often need to attach a PDF export of a document to an existing draft mail message or other document. In these cases "Mail PDF" doesn't work as it creates a new blank mail message each time.

The way I do this currently is to save the document as a PDF and then attach the intermediate file. I would like to achieve the same without dealing with the intermediate file.

I would like a workflow that allows me to print the current document as PDF and copy it to the clipboard.

I tried to create a workflow using Automator and pbcopy, but pbcopy can't be told that the stream of bytes is of type PDF.

Comment: I have been using a script I made based on Gordon Davisson's answer for over seven years now. I [put it on GitHub](https://github.com/mcculley/PrintAsPDFToClipboard) and made a [blog post about it](https://enki.org/2018/07/16/printing-as-pdf-to-the-mac-clipboard/) so others could benefit from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use AppleScript instead:

```
on open PDF_file
    set the clipboard to PDF_file as «class furl»
end open
```

Save it in Application format as something like ~/Library/PDF Services/Copy PDF to clipboard.app, and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Graphic Clipboard (from snip taken with shift-control-command-4 in macOs Sierra):

1. Open Preview and
2. Edit>New from Clipboard (or just command N).  Voilá - it appears in Preview
3. Save or Print from Preview

Text Clipboard (taken from highlighting and command-c)

1. Open Pages, the macOs word processor
2. Open a Blank Document
3. Paste in your clipboard (command-v)
4. Save or print